# Call template based object from derived class

Tags: c++11, templates

I am looking for a solution to this specific problem.
I have a `IOWriter` template class with several methods for writing values of different types.

Now in my base class `TestBase` I create a function template with universal ref input. This forwards the value to the `IOWriter` class instance of the base class.

In a derived class `TestDerived` I have a specialized `IOWriter (i.e. Writer)` class member instance `writer` which should be called by its own function template for forwarding.

```
template <typename WriterType>
struct IOWriter
{
    template < typename T >
    QString Write(WriterType* obj, T value)
    {
        std::cout << "Not Working: TestBase" << std::endl;
        return obj->write(QString("true"));
    }
};

class TestBase
{
    template <typename T>
    friend struct IOWriter;

    //Uses default implementation
    IOWriter<TestBase> writer;

    // pure virtual function called by IOWriter
    virtual QString write(const QString& value) = 0;

public:
    template <typename T>
    QString Write(T&& value)
    {
        return writer.Write(this, std::forward<T>(value));
    }
};

class TestDerived : public TestBase
{
    template <typename T>
    friend struct IOWriter;

    // TestDerived specific implementation
    struct Writer : public IOWriter<TestDerived>
    {
        // Shadows base implementation
        QString Write(TestDerived* obj, bool value)
        {
            std::cout << "Working: TestDerived" << std::endl;
            return obj->write(QString("false"));
        }
    };

    Writer writer;

    // Called by Writer
    QString write(const QString& value) override
    {
        return "derived";
    }

public:
    template <typename T>
    QString Write(T&& value)
    {
        return writer.Write(this, std::forward<T>(value));
    }
};
```

Now inside my code I can call it like this:

```
void working()
{
    int value = 0;
    auto uptr = new TestDerived();
    uptr->Write(value);
    delete uptr;
}
```

That works fine. However when I store the created pointer as TestBase it logically calls `TestBase::Write` and therefore my `TestDerived::writer` is never called:

```
void notWorking()
{
    int value = 0;
    TestBase* uptr = new TestDerived();
    uptr->Write(value);
    delete uptr;
}
```

Now I know that this is correct, however I am looking for a way to let `TestBase::Write` use/call the specialized `TestDerived::Writer` instead of its own.

NOTE: **IOWriter cannot have virtual functions, because there are template member functions in there**

Comment: create a [MCVE] ping me when you do and I will write an answer. Otherwise I just have to guess your design.

Comment: I have updated the code so it can be called right away. Qt is required.

Comment: no, QT is not required to showcase your issue: https://godbolt.org/g/kijkQy

Comment: anyway, thank you for the update. I will write an answer as soon as I have some free time

Answer (score 1):

Ohh, the wonderful time in a programmer's life when he/she realizes the design doesn't fit the needs and contemplates rewriting large parts of the code... I love it :D

Ok, first some must dos that are not related to the issue, but, still:

- make destructors virtual on polymorphic classes.
- use smart pointers, don't use raw new/delete.

Ok, not to the issue at hand:

One solution that I see is to adapt the [Bridge Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) to your problem:

This means:

- make `Write` of `IOWriter` virtual
- in `TestBase` make `writer` a polymorphic base pointer to `IOWriter`
- construct the `TestDerived::writer` with `Writer` instead of `IOWriter`
- remove the `Write` method from `TestDerived`

Here is the final code: (I changed QSString with int to be able to test it faster):

**`final code`**

```
template <typename WriterType> struct IOWriter
{
    virtual int Write(WriterType* obj, int value)
    {
        return obj->write(value * 10 + 3);
    }
    virtual ~IOWriter() = default;
};

struct TestBase
{
    //Uses default implementation
    std::unique_ptr<IOWriter<TestBase>> writer;

    TestBase(std::unique_ptr<IOWriter<TestBase>> writer) : writer{std::move(writer)} {}

    // pure virtual function called by IOWriter
    virtual int write(int value) = 0;

    template <typename T> int Write(T value)
    {
        return writer->Write(this, value);
    }
    virtual ~TestBase() = default;
};

struct TestDerived : public TestBase
{

    // TestDerived specific implementation
    struct Writer : public IOWriter<TestBase>
    {
        // Shadows base implementation
        int Write(TestBase* obj, int value) override
        {
            return obj->write(value * 10 + 4);
        }
    };

    TestDerived() : TestBase(std::make_unique<Writer>()) {}

    // Called by Writer
    int write(int value) override
    {
        return value;
    }
};

auto test()
{
    std::unique_ptr<TestBase> uptr = std::make_unique<TestDerived>();
    return uptr->Write(7);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer first of all. Here is a constraint I cannot change: I cannot make the functions of ```IOWriter``` virtual because I also have function templates in there, so it must work without virtual. Otherwise it would have been easy but I should have added the constraint to the posting (which I do right away). Btw. I am not contemplating, so I am not sure where you got this from but now I am curious if you still think it's so easy.

Comment: @Samxion I never thought it was easy :)

Comment: Thanks anyway bolov for your effort. I'll take a look at type erasure. cheers